# create shared library with main to call undefined function and provide function body in other project

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, shared-libraries

I need to create a shared library using cmake, and I must call function `run()` in a library function. But the project which uses this library should provide the body of this function.

The real cases use systemC which force library to implement main function. To avoid further complexity, I try to simplify the case like this:

*MyInterface.h*

```cpp
void run();
```

*MyLibraryAction.cpp*

```cpp
#include "MyInterface.h"

int main(){
    run();
}
```

The cmake content is:

```sh
add_library(mylib SHARED MyLibraryAction.cpp)

set_target_properties(mylib PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER MyInterface.h)

configure_file(mylib.pc.in mylib.pc @ONLY)

install(
  TARGETS mylib
  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})

install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mylib.pc
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/pkgconfig)
```

I am wondering if that is possible. If so, am I doing it right? is using `extern` relevant in this context?
I am get error when I try to build and create the library:

> undefined reference to `run()`

Comment: Where is the `run` function defined? Where is it implemented? You only seem to have a declaration.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I just wrote these demo files to clarify my problem. I fixed that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: "Also, where is the run function defined?" - "But the project which uses this library should provide the body of this function.". The question is not about why particular **code** doesn't work. The question is about how to make particular **idea** to work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, @Tsyvarev yes the other project should provide the body of `run` function.

Comment: Perhaps this can be solved using [*weak symbols*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol)? You could try making `run` a weak symbol in the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, weak symbols worked fine in this case.

*MyInterface.h*

```cpp
void run();
```

and then have an implementation for `run` function with weak symbol:

*InterfaceWeakImplementation.h*

```cpp
void __attribute__((weak)) run(){
    // pass
}
```

and have the actual implementation in caller project

*InterfaceStrongImplementation.h*

```cpp
void run(){
    // Some real work
}
```